# Azure - attach a disk to multiple Linux VMs - data not updated in attached VMs

Tags: linux, mount, virtual-machine, disk, azure

I am attaching ssdv2 disk to two linux VMs in VMSS using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal?tabs=ubuntu)

First VM is mounted as readwrite and second VM is mounted as readonly.

When I write something to the first VM, the second VM does not see the data in the mounted folder.

When I umount the disk from the second VM and mount again, I see updated data from the first VM. However when I write again to first VM, I still do not see updated data until I remount the disk again.

I am expecting that when I write to the first VM, I can read read the data from the second VM.

I do not want to use NFS of similar solution because is does not fit to my use case. I want to share files used as memory mapped files because of fast seeking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is (should be) expected behaviour. It's quite likely that the writes to the disk from VM1 are not necessarily being completed, so there's nothing to read by VM2. Or alternatively VM2 has read the disk and, knowing it's read only, cached the results so that when the underlying storage is updated by VM1 it's not noticed.

In general you cannot do this without a [cluster-aware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system) filesystem such as [GFS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFS2).